# Casperjs different behavior in another laptop

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have 2 portatiles with the same version of ubuntu and the same version of casperjs (1.1.4) and phantomjs (2.1.1) in one my scripts work well but in the other when I want to access with my script to the frames of a web I jump error:

> CasperError: No element matching selector found: xpath selector: (//frame|//iframe)[@name="ifrw"]

The only difference I find a laptop is an asus i7 and the other a dell i5.

I do not understand what may be happening !!!

Comment: Do you use laptops in different physical locations with different internet providers?

Comment: No, I'm on the same local network.

Comment: Then probably it has to do something with the target page. Have you made screenshots and compared them? Most likely something *is* different, you just didn't notice it yet.